# Create Files Through Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

How would I use Racket to create a file to be able to store and edit user-inputted data, or, for example, a high score. I've read through some of the documentation and haven't found a clear answer on how to do this.

Answer (score 7):

The [Racket Guide](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/) has a chapter on Input and Output. The [first section](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/ports.html) explains reading and writing files, with examples. It says

> Files: The `open-output-file` function opens a file for writing, and 
>   `open-input-file` opens a file for reading.

```
Examples:
> (define out (open-output-file "data"))
> (display "hello" out)
> (close-output-port out)
> (define in (open-input-file "data"))
> (read-line in)
"hello"
> (close-input-port in)
```

> If a file exists already, then `open-output-file` raises an exception by
>   default. Supply an option like `#:exists 'truncate` or `#:exists 'update` 
>   to re-write or update the file:

and so on.

Answer (score 5):

There are some simple functions for reading and writing a file in the `2htdp/batch-io` library: http://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpbatch-io.html . They are somewhat limited in that they access a file only in the same directory as the program itself, but you can do something like:

```
(require 2htdp/batch-io)
(write-file "highscore.txt" "Alice 25\nBob 40\n")
```

to write data to a file (the \n means a newline character), and then

```
(read-lines "highscore.txt")
```

to get back the lines of the file, as a list of strings.